# How to solve: "route name not defined" when it's already defined

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I've already defined route but keeps giving me route not defined error

```
web.php
[1]: https://imgur.com/e78VIqV.jpg "tooltip"

EventController
[2]: https://imgur.com/NAXSUkQ.jpg "tooltip"

view
[3]: https://imgur.com/b5ROHcv.jpg "tooltip"

error
[4]: https://imgur.com/A4lcu0R.jpg "tooltip"
```

Comment: Add some code of your route file so that we can explain?

Comment: I added some images but for some reason it wont appear

Comment: Please add related code.

Comment: i see 2 `semicolons` right after after `event.sched` route

Comment: I edited it but still the same error

Comment: Check my answer you've defined two routes. `event.edit` same file that's why this error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

`event.edit` already exists in `resource('event')`

```
Route::resource('event','eventcontroller');

Verb          Path                         Action  Route Name
GET           /event                       index   event.index
GET           /event/create                create  event.create
POST          /event                       store   event.store
GET           /event/{event}               show    event.show
GET           /event/{event}/edit          edit    event.edit
PUT|PATCH     /event/{event}               update  event.update
DELETE        /event/{event}               destroy event.destroy
```

Your `event.edit` already added in the resource. so if you want call edit method use it directly or you can change it.

change

```
->name('event.edit');
```

TO

```
->name('event.sched.edit');


Route::get('/sched/edit/{id},'Eventcontroller@update')->name('event.sched.edit');
```

Comment: Route [event.sched] not defined.this is my error actually what I'm trying to do is add an event to my database but whenever I try to add it it always puts out an error like route not defined even though I already defined it in web.php

Comment: `"route name not defined” when it's already defined` your question is supposed to be already route defined. Ok tell me which url are you calling. what route you've defined. and what error are you getting?

Comment: when I add an event the url is /sched/add

Comment: Route::get('/sched', 'EventController@create')->name('event.sched');
Route::post('/sched/add', 'EventController@store')->name('event.add');

Comment: Hey I managed to solve it already. I changed the route url thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

i think this is the answer

```
 Route::get('/', 'UserController@index')->name('user.index');
```